# How do I look at my main drive when I have Ubuntu running on a secondary HDD?

Tags: 13.10, mount, hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a secondary drive and I need to access the files on my main HDD (I am using a laptop). How do I do this?

EDIT- I've had an epiphany that you might have to mount it first. How would I go about doing that?

EDIT2- Output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    40M  0 part /media/llamah/DIAGS
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 452.7G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0  11.9G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0  74.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  37.3G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0   5.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

EDIT3- Followed Avinash Raj's advice and got this output:

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: post the output of `lsblk` command.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It has been done.

Comment: which partition are you trying to mount?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Looking at the file sizes, sda5. Otherwise I wouldn't have a clue.

Comment: are you trying to copy only the files from that partition?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just view, edit, usual file editing. Just make the partition accessable from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below commands to mount `/dev/sda5` partition.

```
sudo mkdir /media/gallery
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda5 /media/gallery
```

After running the above commands, go into `/media/gallery` directory via nautilus. There you can find the files of your `/dev/sda5` partition.

Comment: Please check question.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late but yes, this worked for me.